# Trigger jquery .on() on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find out if I can trigger some javascript code when page has loaded and not only on `keyup`

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.some-class', function (e)
{
    // Some code
});
```

I have tried the following and that didn't work (my research indicate that it shouldn't work either):

```
$(document).on('keyup load', '.some-class', function (e)
{
    // Some code
});

$(window).on('keyup load', '.some-class', function (e)
{
    // Some code
});
```

UPDATE:

My question seems to be unclear in regards to what I want to accomplish. The code works fine when using `keyup` in an input field.
But I also want the code to run when the page loads.

I could do this but I am looking for a solution that are more elegant.

```
hello();

function hello() {
    // Some code
}

$(window).on('keyup load', '.some-class', function (e)
{
    hello();
});
```

Comment: I don't understand, jquery runs on page load anyway. `$( document ).ready(function() {//jQuery stuff here});` you put your events within that.

Comment: what is not working for you?What error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst you CAN trigger the keyup function on page load, I wouldn't recommend it. You're much better off defining the function you want to run elsewhere, then calling it on both load and keyup.

This way if you ever want to add anything to the keyup event that doesn't need to run on load, you can.

Something like, but not necessarily this, would work:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    // Do some function stuff
    return;
}

$(document).ready(myFunction);
$('.myElement').on('keyup', myFunction);
```

Or if you need to pass arguments to the function (which is a little closer to your use-case):

```
var myFunction = function(args) {
    // Do some function stuff
    return;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction(args)
});
$('.myElement').on('keyup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    myFunction(args);
    // You can add more code here that won't be triggered on load
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are searching for **$( document ).ready()**. When the document is *ready* just run the code

```
$( document ).ready(function() { /* YOUR CODE HERE (maybe the $(document).on('key up'... */})
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like you are wanting something like the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //Code Here
)};
```

Or window load (which was deprecated in 1.8 thanks to @charlietfl):

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    //Code Here
)};
```

Comment: `.load(function)` is deprecated

Comment: Cant see anything about it being deprecated in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Because that is the ajax shortcut signature ... see http://api.jquery.com/load-event/